# CURL: Failed to connect to exampleurl.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: php, web-services, curl

Whenever I try to connect API through CURL (PHP) I got " Failed to connect to exampleurl.com port 443: Connection refused" error while postman responses successfully. Code is running in dev server.

Here is my curl code

```
$ch       = curl_init();
$headers  = array(
  "Authorization: $this->header_token" // my token
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch); //giving error
}
 curl_close($ch);

if($http_status == 200){
  return json_decode($res,true);
}
```

One thing, I got this error recently, previously it works fine, no issue at all.
Any suggestion or solution, pls help.

Comment: If it worked before then something else might have changed. Can you ping that url through cli? It might be a firewall issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this option i have faced the same issue then it solved

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually there is some server issue, they resolved and it works.